# Stream filter method is not executed every time

Tags: java

```
public class Test {


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    long filtered = Stream.of("test1", "test2", "test3")
        .filter(getPredicate())
        .count();
    System.out.println(filtered);

  }

  private static Predicate<String> getPredicate() {
    System.out.println("print this");//<-- this line was printed only once
    return item -> item.contains("test");
  }

}
```

I expected the above code to 3 times print out **print this**. But it printed only once, can someone explain?

Comment: How many times does your code call `getPredicate()`?

Comment: it was called once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getPredicate()` is called before `filter()` so you see "print this" once. The predicate you return is called three times, if you wanted to see that try:

```
private static Predicate<String> getPredicate() {
   System.out.println("print this");
  return item -> {
       System.out.println("print that");
       return item.contains("test");
  };
}
```